# How to deserialize JSON object into Kotlin Pair with Jackson?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I have a simple data class representing a city

```kotlin
data class City(
    val name: String,
    val centroid: Coordinates
)
```

For external compatibility reasons the `Coordinates` type is defined as a `typealias`

```kotlin
typealias Coordinates = Pair<Double, Double>

val Coordinates.lat
    get() = first

val Coordinates.lon
    get() = second
```

How can I configure Jackson so that it's able to deserialize following JSON into an instance of `City`?

```
{
  "name": "Praha",
  "centroid": {
    "lat": 50.2141,
    "lon": 14.42342
  }
}
```

Comment: Use low level api (define your type adapter) instead of object binding api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really have to preserve compatibility you could write your own Serializer & Deserializer, for example:

```kotlin
object CoordinatesConversions {

    const val LATITUDE_FIELD_NAME = "lat"
    const val LONGITUDE_FIELD_NAME = "lon"

    object Serializer : JsonSerializer<Coordinates>() {
        override fun serialize(value: Coordinates, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
            with(gen) {
                writeStartObject()
                writeNumberField(LATITUDE_FIELD_NAME, value.first)
                writeNumberField(LONGITUDE_FIELD_NAME, value.second)
                writeEndObject()
            }
        }
    }

    object Deserializer : JsonDeserializer<Coordinates>() {
        override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Coordinates {
            val node = p.readValueAsTree<JsonNode>()

            val lat = node.get(LATITUDE_FIELD_NAME).asDouble()
            val lon = node.get(LONGITUDE_FIELD_NAME).asDouble()

            return Coordinates(lat, lon)
        }
    }
}
```

Also specify which serializers should be used for your City model

```kotlin
data class City(
    val name: String,

    @JsonSerialize(using = CoordinatesConversions.Serializer::class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CoordinatesConversions.Deserializer::class)
    val center: Coordinates
)
```

A fully working example:

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

private typealias Coordinates = Pair<Double, Double>

object CoordinatesConversions {

    const val LATITUDE_FIELD_NAME = "lat"
    const val LONGITUDE_FIELD_NAME = "lon"

    object Serializer : JsonSerializer<Coordinates>() {
        override fun serialize(value: Coordinates, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
            with(gen) {
                writeStartObject()
                writeNumberField(LATITUDE_FIELD_NAME, value.first)
                writeNumberField(LONGITUDE_FIELD_NAME, value.second)
                writeEndObject()
            }
        }
    }

    object Deserializer : JsonDeserializer<Coordinates>() {
        override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Coordinates {
            val node = p.readValueAsTree<JsonNode>()

            val lat = node.get(LATITUDE_FIELD_NAME).asDouble()
            val lon = node.get(LONGITUDE_FIELD_NAME).asDouble()

            return Coordinates(lat, lon)
        }
    }
}

object StackOverflow {

    private val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
        configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true)
    }

    data class City(
        val name: String,

        @JsonSerialize(using = CoordinatesConversions.Serializer::class)
        @JsonDeserialize(using = CoordinatesConversions.Deserializer::class)
        val center: Coordinates
    )

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        val city = City("Cair Paravel", 13.37 to 42.0)

        val jsonOutput = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(city)
        println(jsonOutput)

        val deserializedCity = objectMapper.readValue<City>(jsonOutput)
        println(deserializedCity)
    }
}
```

I still think it would be better to try and move away from using Pairs to represent such a concrete data structure and I think it would benefit you in the future.

For example, it's not always clear which standard that's being used when representing a geographical point, some vendors use `(lat, lng)`, others use `(lng, lat)`. Even though you have defined named property getters on top of the alias, you wouldn't need to go through the hassle of defining a custom serializer and deserializer which is always nice.

Comment: Very nice answer! Thank you. <3

In the code did you maybe forgot to use the `LATITUDE/LONGITURE_FIELD_NAME` constants in the deserializer?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out for you :) You're correct, I forgot to use them in the Deserializer, I'll update the answer.