# Kotlin & Jackson: type error when specifying custom serialisation for a data class field

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, jvm

I have a Kotlin data class that is serialised to JSON in a Spring Boot project. I'd like to customise how date is formatted when serialising to JSON. The name of the field should be serialised using default rules. That expresses what I'd like to do:

```kotlin
class ZonedDateTimeSerialiser : JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime>() {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun serialize(value: ZonedDateTime, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider?) {
        val parseDate: String? = value.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw"))
        .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
        gen.writeString(parseDate)
    }
}

data class OrderNotesRequest(
    @JsonSerialize(using = ZonedDateTimeSerialiser::class)
    val date: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
)
```

But I get a type error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
KClass<out (JsonSerializer<Any!>..JsonSerializer<*>?)>
Found:
KClass<ZonedDateTimeSerialiser>
```

I did try switching the parameter to annotation to `contentUsing` but the type error remained the same.

Comment: I just have superficial knowledge of Kotlin but I think you missed the [`override`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#overriding-methods) keyword when overriding the `serialize` method, it may be related to the issue. Having said that, the rest of the code looks fine to me. Please, consider review working examples in the [Jackson module for Kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/blob/cf1833f7c3be2af032412a4c23af536438627bc6/src/test/kotlin/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/test/KClassSerializerDeserializerTest.kt) or ...

Comment: ... in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794386/how-to-deserialize-json-object-into-kotlin-pair-with-jackson) related SO question. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think you need to put it like this, provided you want to keep "date" as name in json -


@JsonSerialize(using = ZonedDateTimeSerialiser.class)
data class OrderNotesRequest(
    val date: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is working for me

```
object JacksonRun {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val objMapper = ObjectMapper().apply {
            registerModule(KotlinModule())
        }
        val order = OrderNotesRequest()
        println(objMapper.writeValueAsString(order))
    }

}

data class OrderNotesRequest(
    @JsonSerialize(using = ZonedDateTimeSerialiser::class)
    val date: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
)

class ZonedDateTimeSerialiser : JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime>() {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun serialize(value: ZonedDateTime, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider?) {
        val parseDate: String = value.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw"))
            .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
        gen.writeString(parseDate)
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.0")
}
```

Gives me output:

```
{"date":"2022-03-21T10:29:19.381498Z"}
```

Do make sure you have the correct import for `JsonSerializer`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer
```

and add `override` marker to `serialize` method

Comment: it was the import 